# Please rename [skype] to [skype-for-web]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

While the usage guidance for [skype](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skype) points out that it's only for "Skype for Web", we still get people asking about the installable software.<sup>1,2</sup>

We can shortcut that to be specific with the tag by making it [skype-for-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skype-for-web).

---

<sup>1</sup> Because people just don't read online
<sup>2</sup> Also, some people think that if a tag exists, questions must be on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have renamed [skype](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skype) to [skype-for-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skype-for-web), some questions in that tag might need a clean up/delete though.